# Android Studio ListView - null pointer exception when trying to extract text from selected item

Tags: android, listview, exception, android-studio

I'm trying to save text from the selected item of a ListView in OnItemClick.

I've tried so many different methods to no avail, I think I'm missing something really stupidly obvious here...

```
SnakesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String choice = SnakesListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(SnakeList.this, SnakeProfile.class);
            intent.putExtra("SelectedSnakeName", choice);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

The data is being displayed fine, I just can't seem to reference it.
The line causing the exception:

```
String choice = SnakesListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

Full code for this activity

```
public class SnakeList extends Activity {

ListView SnakesListView;
Cursor cursor;
Button NewSnakeBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_snake_list);

    SnakesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SnakesListView);
    NewSnakeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NewSnake);

    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("snakeDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null); // ACCESSES DB
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM snakes", null); // SETS cursor TO RESULTS OF QUERY
    List<String> SnakeNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter SnakeNamesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, SnakeNamesList);
    SnakeNamesList.clear(); // REMOVES ANY NAMES CURRENTLY IN NAME ARRAY TO AVOID DUPLICATES
    SnakesListView.setAdapter(SnakeNamesAdapter);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst(); // MOVES CURSOR TO FIRST POSITION
        do SnakeNamesList.add(cursor.getString(0)); // RETURNS STRING FROM FIRST COLUMN (NAME)
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    NewSnakeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SnakeList.this, NewSnake.class));
        }
    });

    SnakesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String choice = SnakesListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(SnakeList.this, SnakeProfile.class);
            intent.putExtra("SelectedSnakeName", choice);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: No use of referencing the ListView; you can get the value from adapter itself. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No use of referencing the `ListView`; you can get the value from adapter itself.

Change

```
String choice = SnakesListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

to

```
String choice = SnakeNamesAdapter.getItem(position).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks! Only thing I didn't try hah

Answer (score 0):

declare the string arraylist(SnakeNamesList) as global variable and

change

```
String choice = SnakesListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

to

```
String choice = SnakeNamesList.get(position);
```